# Identifying keys by looking at values in a dictionary

Tags: python

- I have a dictionary with key-value pairs like `{a : (b,c,d,e)}`.
- If i encounter a tuple `(b,c,d,e)`, i want to lookup in dictionary, the key having the same tuple as a value and delete that key from the dictionary. Can it be done like this in python?

Comment: `{a,[b,c,d,e]}` is not a dictionary and `[b,c,d,e]` is not a tuple.

Comment: sryy...my bad. a is the key and the tuple [b,c,d,e] is the value for that key

Comment: Ok, so you have a tuple `(b,c,d,e)` and you want to find that value in the dictionary and then delete that key/value pair?

Comment: yes, thats right. And i have lots of entries in the dictionary and i have to search multiple times the whole dictionary. Is there an efficient way to make the search faster?

Comment: The point of dictionaries is to look up a key and get a value. If you're trying to look up a value quickly, you've constructed your dictionary backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `list()`,`set()`, or `tuple()` because `list(dict)`or `tuple(dict)` or `set(dict)`  returns the keys of a dictionary and you can iterate over these returned keys and pop items from the dictionary, 
And as Lattyware suggested ,to stop the iteration after removal of one value use `break` statement after `pop()`.

```
div={'a':(1,2,3,4),'b':[1,2],'c':(1,2,3,4)}
tup=(1,2,3,4)
for x in set(div):
    if div[x]==tup:
        div.pop(x)

print(div)        

{'b': [1,2]}
```

Comment: no, i dont want to delete all the key/value pairs when i encounter matching entry. I want to delete only one for each match. For example, if i have {a:[b,c,d,e]}, {b:[b,c,d,e]}, {c:[b,c,d,e]}, {d:[b,c,d,e]} and i encounter (b,c,d,e) tuple, i want to delete only 1 entry, i.e. {a:[b,c,d,e]}. If i encounter the tuple (b,c,d,e) next time, i want to delete another entry, i.e. {b:[b,c,d,e]}, and so on...

Comment: In addition to the question being unclear, I don't see why you'd pick `set` here specifically... what is the difference / advantage over `list` since the keys are already unique?

Comment: @agf In 3.x, a dict view changes with the dict, so you would receive an error as it changed while you iterated over it. This is protection against that, by creating a new set, it doesn't rely on the dict.

Comment: @rockluke You can just add a `break` after the `pop()` to do what you want with this one. Although do note as dicts have no order, it will be one **arbitrary** value.

Comment: @Lattyware Yes, I clarified. I meant why `set` rather than anything else? Although, in this case, since he's only removing one item, that error is irrelevent.

Comment: @agf Why not a set? A list carries order, something not needed here. Dictionary keys are a set, why not store them as one?

Comment: @Lattyware Because there is more overhead to creating a `set` than a `list` or `tuple`.

Comment: @agf I'll edit my answer and will add `list()` and `tuple()` approach too.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thank you for the solution but 'set' is taking too long to process only some entries...isn't there any faster approach to this problem?